# Interpreting a probability problem regarding independence

Tags: probability

[image]

### Attempt

Let $X_i$ be event student become sick in week $i$. We know $P(X_i) = 17/23$. Maybe this notation is unnecesary? Now, I think maybe geometric

since we want 3 weeks no sick and because of independence

$$ (1 - 17/23)^3 = \left( \frac{6}{23} \right)^3 $$

what I dont understand is what they mean by "before the 2nd week". Do they mean the second week from the beginning paragraph? Then, we just would have

$$ \left( \frac{6}{23} \right)^3 \cdot \frac{17}{23} = 0.013  $$

is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$X_n = \begin{cases}1,& \text{ if no student is sick in week $n$}\\0,& \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$ for each $n=1,2,\ldots$ 
and let $$\tau = \inf\left\{n>0: \sum_{k=1}^n X_k = n-2\right\} $$ be the second week where at least one student becomes sick. There are at least three weeks where no students are sick before week $\tau$ precisely when $\tau > 4$; these are the outcomes with $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)$ taking values in
$$
\{ (1,1,1,1), (1,1,1,0), (1,1,0,1), (1,0,1,1), (0,1,1,1) \}
$$
Now,
$$
\mathbb P(1,1,1,1) = \left(\frac{17}{23}\right)^4
$$
and
$$
\mathbb P(1,1,1,0) = \mathbb(1,1,0,1) = \mathbb(1,0,1,1) = \mathbb(0,1,1,1) = \left(\frac{17}{23}\right)^3\cdot\frac6{23},
$$
and so
$$
\mathbb P(\tau > 4) = \left(\frac{17}{23}\right)^4 + 3\cdot \left(\frac{17}{23}\right)^3\cdot\frac6{23} = \frac{171955}{279841} \approx 0.614474.
$$